# Java/Groovy: allow only constant string parameter for method

Tags: java, groovy

Groovy/Java question.
How can I make the below method:

```
public void log_something(String someText)
```

to be restricted only to be used with Constant String literals?

I.e. allowed:

```
log_something("some text here")
```

Not allowed:

```
log_something("some dynamic text"+someOtherTextVariable)
```

It should be compile-time check. Ideally without AST.﻿

Comment: There is no way to do that, but good news, `String` is immutable so even a "variable" `String` is a "constant".

Comment: No, it's not. Why the way, what is the use case of this?

Comment: that's sad. I am working on "manageable" logging system for PCI-DSS compliant applications. I want to let operator to configure log to "ban" message in case it contains clear MasterCard Card Number (PAN). But if programmer will pass some dynamic string on runtime to logger, it is hard to restrict it from being logged.

Comment: well I am thinking of Groovy dynamic method, i.e. new LogSomething().Here_goes_the_message_and_not_possible_to_change_it_on_runtime(). But its too ugly...

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean...? As others have said, all String instances are immutable. You can concatenate two (or more) strings together, but that produces a **new String instance** when you do that. The new String instance is its own thing and is similarly immutable.

Comment: @nasukkin, I want to have a compile check that programmer won't add any variables as part of the method String parameter.

Comment: Do you mean to restrict the log to not contain any runtime data? Doesn't that make the log more or less useless? You can do it though; just separate the log messages into a properties file, and then use the property key as input to your log method.

Comment: It seems more to the point, given the use case that you describe, that whatever string is passed in as the argument should not contain a "MasterCard Card Number (PAN)". If you can characterize that as a regular expression pattern, you could, instead, prevent messages that contain the forbidden pattern. On my current project, we regularly filter out sensitive customer data from our logs. It's not that hard.

Comment: @Steinar - your understanding is absolutely correct. Run-time data is passed via special objects, that can be explicitly controlled via log XML config. So its only Programmer's message that has to be now restricted from dynamic data to prevent sensitive data to be displayed. Your approach is valid - thanks for this. The issue with it is that as per my concept Debug messages also play role of comments.

Comment: @Balrog - thanks for suggestion. But I avoid using reg. expression because I want to make operator-friendly configuration and not all operators know Reg. expressions.

Comment: As of now I have in my mind: debug_logger.HERE_GOES_MY_COMPILE_TIME_DEBUG_MESSAGE_WHICH_ALSO_IS_A_COMMENT_FOR_CODE

Comment: I think in the case that you describe you also have to make sure that `log_something("some dynamic text $someOtherTextVariable")` cannot be executed in Groovy

Comment: @Gergely Toth, good point - thank you. But I think it will be run-time check in this case.

Comment: "Compile time check" without dealing with ASTs is not going to happen.  You're going to need to figure out how to write a Groovy compiler plugin to do this; nothing short of that is going to suffice.

Comment: This is drifting into a discussion better suited for Programmers Stack Exchange, but one option is to accept an enum instead of a String. However, the trade-off is that there is a finite # of log messages (or codes) that are known in advance.